# Sql, get category tree for values from one table, names and ids

Tags: postgresql, query, tree

**What I need**
I need select all ids or names from table "category" (all chidrens) until category_id is 0 (main category).

**Example**
On web there is product with category tree.

[image: web_category]

In table "category" I have parent category id as 0, and other children categories ids are defined by numbers as this.

[image]

How can I in sql show all categories tree in one field? For example.

```
Úvod > Bydlení > Barvy a Laky > Vnitřní barvy
```

What is the simplest way to do that?

DBMS = PostgreSQL ver. 10.9.

Thank you very much.

BR.

**Edited, updated, for ids main category id is not present.**

By Akina solution.

```
with recursive

cte as(
select category_id,category_parent,category_name::text
from s_category
where category_parent = 0
union all
select
s_category.category_id,
s_category.category_parent,
concat(cte.category_name, ' > ', s_category.category_name)
from s_category,cte
where cte.category_id = s_category.category_parent
),

cte2 as(
select category_id,category_parent,category_name::text
from s_category
where category_parent = 0
union all
select
s_category.category_id,
s_category.category_parent,
concat(cte2.category_id, ' : ', s_category.category_id)
from s_category,cte2
where cte2.category_id = s_category.category_parent
)

select
cte.category_name as tree_category,
cte2.category_id as tree_id,
s_product.product_id as itemID,
s_product.product_id as itemGroupID,
product_shop_id as productCode,
product_ean as ean,
product_name as title,
product_short_label as description,
product_url as link,
filename as image,
price_tax as price,
price_rec as priceOriginal,
producer_name as brand

from
s_product

left join s_product_image on s_product.product_id = s_product_image.product_id
left join s_pricelist_generated_lists on s_product.product_id = s_pricelist_generated_lists.product_id
left join s_producer on s_product.producer_id = s_producer.producer_id
left join cte on s_product.category_id = cte.category_id
left join cte2 on s_product.category_id = cte2.category_id

where
s_product.product_id = '133471'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example.

Structure and data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tree (id INT, parent INT, name VARCHAR);

INSERT INTO tree VALUES
(1,0,'root'),
(2,1,'branch 1'),
(3,1,'branch 2'),
(4,2,'branch 3'),
(5,2,'branch 4'),
(6,4,'branch 5'),
(7,6,'branch 6'),
(8,3,'leaf 1'),
(9,5,'leaf 2'),
(10,7,'leaf 3');
```

Query:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS ( SELECT t1.id, t1.parent, t1.name
                        FROM tree t1
                        LEFT JOIN tree t2 ON t1.id = t2.parent
                        WHERE t2.parent is null
                        UNION ALL
                        SELECT t1.id, t1.parent, CONCAT(t1.name, ' > ', t2.name)
                        FROM tree t1
                        JOIN cte t2 ON t1.id = t2.parent 
                      )
SELECT name
FROM cte
WHERE parent = 0;
```

Output:

```sql
                    name
---------------------------------------------------------
root > branch 2 > leaf 1
root > branch 1 > branch 4 > leaf 2
root > branch 1 > branch 3 > branch 5 > branch 6 > leaf 3
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=52a31ec8363bbba8b63b662321da6140)

---

UPDATE:

```sql
WITH recursive cte AS ( SELECT t1.category_id, t1.category_parent,    t1.category_name::text
                    FROM s_category t1
                    LEFT JOIN s_category t2 ON t1.category_id = t2.category_parent
                    WHERE t2.category_parent is null
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT t1.category_id, t1.category_parent,     CONCAT(t1.category_name, ' > ', t2.category_name)
                    FROM s_category t1
                    JOIN cte t2 ON t1.category_id = t2.category_parent 
                  )
select 

cte.category_name AS category,
s_product.product_id as itemID,
s_product.product_id as itemGroupID,
product_shop_id as productCode,
product_ean as ean,
product_name as title,
product_short_label as description,
product_url as link,
filename as image,
price_tax as price,
price_rec as priceOriginal,
producer_name as brand,
-- as category,
s_category.category_id as categoryID
-- as hierarchy,
-- as params,
-- as name,
-- as value,
-- as labels

from

public.s_product
left join s_product_image on s_product.product_id =             s_product_image.product_id
left join s_pricelist_generated_lists on s_product.product_id = s_pricelist_generated_lists.product_id
left join cte on s_product.category_id = cte.category_id
left join s_producer on s_product.producer_id = s_producer.producer_id

where

s_product.product_id='133471'
and s_pricelist_generate
```

UPDATE2:

Alternative CTE - producing URL for each node.

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE 
cte AS ( SELECT id, parent, name
         FROM tree
         WHERE parent = 0
       UNION ALL
         SELECT tree.id, tree.parent, CONCAT(cte.name, ' > ', tree.name)
         FROM tree, cte
         WHERE cte.id = tree.parent
       )
```

Comment: Thank you, now it is working. I updated my code in my question. Last question. When I want to do it same thing, but for ids (for example 6439 >6464 > 6669), is new cte needed, or can I do it just little modificatin in existing cte or in select? Thank you.

Comment: Add one more field which collects IDs by the same way.

Comment: I did, but it shows me 6464:6669 instead 6439:6464:6669, main category is missing. And how can I display first value 'Úvod' in first cte? Question/code updated above. Thanks.